# Restarting application running in Docker container breaks stack networking

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two node applications, Foo and Bar, running in Docker containers. Foo is configured to communicate with Bar through the Docker Compose default network through HTTP requests to `Bar:3000`.

I am using `nodemon` to automatically restart the apps inside the container when code changes. However, whenever Bar resets, the networking breaks such that any future requests from Foo fail with "Connection refused" errors until I restart the entire stack.

Here is the portion of the `docker-compose.yml` for those services.

```
services:
  Bar:
    build:
      context: auth
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: ${NPM_TOKEN}
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=${MONGO_URI}
      - JWT_KEY=${JWT_KEY}
      - OKTA_ISSUER=${OKTA_ISSUER}
      - OKTA_CLIENT_ID=${OKTA_CLIENT_ID}
      - OKTA_API_BASE_URL=${OKTA_API_BASE_URL}
      - OKTA_API_USERS_TOKEN=${OKTA_API_USERS_TOKEN}
      - NODE_PORT=3000
      - NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}
      - GOOGLE_reCAPTCHA_SECRET=${GOOGLE_reCAPTCHA_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 8082:3000
    volumes:
      - ./auth/:/usr/src/app
    command: npm run dev
  Foo:
    build:
      context: api
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: ${NPM_TOKEN}
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=${MONGO_URI}
      - JWT_KEY=${JWT_KEY}
      - NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}
      - AUTH_ENDPOINT_URL=http://auth:3000
      - CHAT_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:8083
      - MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:8084
      - GROUPCHAT_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:8085
    ports:
      - 9000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: npm run dev -- -L
```

Comment: Can you show the compose ?

Comment: @EricNordeloGaliano I added the relevant section of the compose file.

Comment: maybe your volume is overwriting some important variable to establish a secure connection. But thats hard to say without looking inside of your container

Comment: Have you checked Bar’s network setting after restarted?